# How do I loop the opening and closing of a web page on widnows 10 run prompt?

Tags: javascript, loops, command-prompt

So been trying to solve this for a few days now. does anyone know the code to open and close and then open again and close on loop a web page

Saw a few people try on different sites but non of the promopts have worked, so id be happy to take suggestions, thanks guys

Comment: from a command prompt?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. 
Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: What is it that you want to use this for? Seems like a question based on an idea you had to solve a problem rather than the initial problem. If this is exactly what you need for whatever reason, please edit to include what you have tried so far and why it didn't work, including errors if any.